# Resize <tr> and <td> with image inside by percent

Tags: html

I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
        <td><img src="..."/></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Every image has a different size and is huge.

Right now, I see them like this:

```
This is the view:
----------------------------------------
| This is the table:                   |
| -------------------------------------|------------------
| |             |             |        |     |           |
| |             |             |        |     |           |
| |             |             |        |     |           |
| |    img1     |     img2    |     img|3    |    img4   |
| |             |             |        |     |           |
| |             |             |        |     |           |
| |             |             |        |     |           |
| |             |             |        |     |           |
| |------------------------------------|-----------------|
| |             |             |        |     |           |
---------------------------------------      |           |
  |             |             |              |           |
  |             |             |              |           |
  |     img5    |     img6    |      img7    |    img8   |
  |             |             |              |           |
  |             |             |              |           |
  |             |             |              |           |
  --------------------------------------------------------

                       ...and so on...
```

I want to fit the width of table into view.

I want to set the `width` of every `<td>` to 25% and and every `<tr>` to 50%. As result, to see 8 images in view.

The table has more `<tr>`, but I want to can complete see 2 `<tr>` at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the width you can set table to width 100% and td width 25%;
https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/gOMrELb

```css
td {
  width: 25%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It not works. The total width of table is still outside of the view.

Comment: Use the table-layout:fixed style for the table and set the image width to 100%;